# Insert a record only if it is not present

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a query to insert some records, the record must be unique. If it exists I need the recorded ID else if it doesnt exist I want insert it and get the new ID. I wrote that query but it doesnt work.

```
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'category_x'
WHERE NO EXISTS (INSERT INTO tags('name', 'slug') VALUES('Category X','category_x'));
```

Comment: Can't really understand what you are trying to attempt. Is your ID an auto_increment primary key?

Comment: Well selecting an id from an query that comes from an application is bad and can/will cause race conditions on long terms runs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [UPSERT](http://www.wordnik.com/words/upsert) (i.e. UPdate or inSERT).

```
INSERT INTO tags
('name', 'slug')
VALUES('Category X','category_x')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
'slug' = 'category_x'
```

MySql Reference: **13.2.5.3.** [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: +1 for the UPSERT, like the sound off that... ANSI should include this into the ANSI SQL standard..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'category_x'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tags('name', 'slug') VALUES('Category X','category_x');
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT id FROM tags WHERE slug = 'category_x'
END
```

But you can leave the ELSE part and SELECT the id, this way the query will always return the id, irrespective of the insert...

Comment: BEGIN ... END syntax can only be used within stored procedures, functions, triggers end events (MySQL 5.6) see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has nice `REPLACE`. It is easy to use and remember it's syntax as same as `INSERT`.
in you case, just run following query.

```
REPLACE INTO tags('name', 'slug') VALUES('Category X','category_x')
```

It acts like INSERT when no unique constraint violation. If duplicated value found on PK or UNIQUE key, then other columns will be UPDATED with given values. It is done by DELETE duplicated record and INSERT new record.